# Subtract two plots from one another

Tags: plotting

I have the graph below that is generated from a list of data ("data1"). If I have an equation that generates the second plot (see code below), which corresponds to the second peak of the first image, how can I subtract plot 1 from plot 2?.

```
    peak = amp2UserDefined*
      Exp[-(x - x02UserDefined)^2/sigma2UserDefined^2]
peakplot = Plot[peak, {x, 60, 120}, PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}]
```

Edit: The output of "peak" is 0.077 E^(-0.0349375 (-93.4 + x)^2) and data1 is can be found here https://pastebin.com/tn8PAPTB

[image: Plot 1]

[image: Plot 2]

Comment: it will help to provide `Data1` or code to generate it.

Comment: Thank you Nasser. I have added data1 in the edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant:

```
data2 = Select[data1, 60 <= #[[1]] <= 120 &];
f[x_] := 0.077 E^(-0.0349375 (-93.4 + x)^2)
Union[Transpose[{data2[[;; , 1]], 
      data2[[;; , 2]] - f /@ data2[[;; , 1]]}], Complement[data1, data2]]//ListPlot
```

[image]

**EDIT**

To answer a comment about subtracting both peaks:

```
f1[x_] := 0.07 E^(-0.170753 (-78.4 + x)^2)
Union[Transpose[{data2[[;; , 1]], 
      data2[[;; , 2]] - f /@ data2[[;; , 1]] - f1 /@ data2[[;; , 1]]}], 
      Complement[data1, data2]];
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Alx! This seems to work very well!. I am also open to other suggestions but this code does the job!

Comment: Alx! One question, could you tell me how to modify your code in case I wanted to also subtract the first peak from the data1?. The output of the first peak is 0.07 E^(-0.170753 (-78.4 + x)^2). Thank you !

Comment: First you need to know `x` coordinates of that range in `data1`, next is the same, it should be simply a replacement of `{60, 120}` range.

Comment: Got it! But what I mean is how to subtract both at the same time from data1. They both have the same coordinates.

Comment: I've edited my answer to subtract both peaks.

Comment: I tried to do so but I'm still struggle with the import. What is the best way to get data1 into Mathematice when the file is in the NotebookPath?